Assigning pins to the Secure context of a TF-M application
Unless I'm wrong, the architecture of the TFM application seems not to allow the assignment of a peripheral (e.g. a LED pin) to the Secure context of TrustZone as it is the case with simple TrustZone applications.
I couldn't find on the Internet such example of customization of the Secure context of the TFM application to assign peripherals to the Secure part of the application.
Is there a way to do so? If yes, how? I'm using the B-U585I-IOT02A IoT Discovery board from ST Microelectronics.
